# hibernate org.objectweb.asm.classwriter

Tags: java, hibernate, java-bytecode-asm

i get this error when i run my java application i work with hibernate :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter

and i added all jars of asm

console:

```
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 2.1.6
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using CGLIB reflection optimizer
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from file: hibernate.cfg.xml
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Mapping resource: org/projet/Timesheet.hbm.xml
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Binder bindRootClass
INFO: Mapping class: org.projet.Timesheet -> timesheet
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing one-to-many association mappings
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing one-to-one association property references
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration secondPassCompile
INFO: processing foreign key constraints
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Maximim outer join fetch depth: 2
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use outer join fetching: true
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: using driver: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timesheet
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=root, password=manel}
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Transaction strategy: net.sf.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of process level read-write cache is not recommended)
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use scrollable result sets: true
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Use JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): true
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: false
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: cache provider: net.sf.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
12 mai 2011 09:57:53 net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configureCaches
INFO: instantiating and configuring caches
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:215)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at net.sf.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:791)
    at org.projet.ModelTime.configure(ModelTime.java:28)
    at org.projet.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
```

Comment: Which version of ASM did you add?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the supplied library version is not having the classes required. There is no general fix though but you can try with this approach which worked for me.

All you need to do is to have a proper exclusion of ASM libraries from hibernate and a separate inclusion of it. Seems fuzzy but take a look at the snippet from a working pom.xml. The intent behind this approach is to include a more later version of the dependent library which may be required by some other 3rd library in the project.

for including hibernate entity manager i am using following code.

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Here I am explicitly excluding asm from the hibernate-entity manager inclusion and next to it I am including it separately

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>${asm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the properties are. These version choices worked for me in the latest project.

```
    <properties>
            <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
            <asm.version>3.3</asm.version>
    </properties>
```

Hope, this solves your problem.

Comment: this only works for maven projects, which the op didn't say he uses.